# Allow multiple K8s resources in a JSON

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I have a YAML file which contains multiple resources Deployment and Service.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: petclinic
  name: petclinic
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: petclinic
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: petclinic
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: arey/springboot-petclinic
          name: springboot-petclinic
          resources: {}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: petclinic
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: petclinic
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

I'm creating a similar file in JSON. I was able to create the deployment resource with JSON and successfully deploy, but when i attempt to include the service resource, it's failing. Any assistance on where i'm going wrong would be much appreciate. Here's the below snippet for JSON.

```
{
   "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
   "kind": "Deployment",
   "metadata": {
      "creationTimestamp": null,
      "labels": {
         "app": "petclinic"
      },
      "name": "petclinic"
   },
   "spec": {
      "replicas": 2,
      "selector": {
         "matchLabels": {
            "app": "petclinic"
         }
      },
      "strategy": {},
      "template": {
         "metadata": {
            "labels": {
               "app": "petclinic"
            }
         },
         "spec": {
            "containers": [
               {
                  "image": "arey/springboot-petclinic",
                  "name": "springboot-petclinic",
                  "resources": {},
                  "ports": [
                     {
                        "containerPort": 8080
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "status": {}
}

{
   "apiVersion": "v1",
   "kind": "Service",
   "metadata": {
        "name": "petclinic"
   },
   "spec": {
      "type": "LoadBalancer",
      "selector": {
       
            "app": "petclinic"
         
      },
        
            "ports": [
               {
                  "port": 8080,
                  "targetPort": 8080,
                  "protocol": "TCP",
                  "name": "http"                   
                  ]
             }     
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a syntax error in your Service resource (array closing bracket in `ports`). It should be:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Service",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "petclinic"
  },
  "spec": {
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "selector": {
      "app": "petclinic"
    },
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 8080,
        "targetPort": 8080,
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "name": "http"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To make the file a valid JSON file, you can wrap the definitions in the `List` resource:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "List",
  "items": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "Deployment",
      ...
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "Service",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a question. Is it possible to enclose the two root objects( deployment and services) in array so the JSON syntax is satisfied? Can i have the syntax?

Comment: @Coolbreeze in the JSON array itself no, but you can wrap them with the `List` resource. See edited response

Comment: Huge thanks for edited response. That was exactly what i was looking for. Appreciate the time spent on assisting me on this.

Comment: "`kind: List` is a client-side, internal implementation detail for processing collections that might be of different kinds of object. Avoid depending on kind: List in automation or other code." (source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#collections)

Answer (score 1):

You could first apply the yaml using `kubectl` and then get a json back using `kubectl get deploy,services -o json > example.json`

The correct syntax for a json is to have `,` between two resources instead of `---` as you use in yaml

```
...
    // deployment
},
{
    // service
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, `kind: List` can be used when using `kubectl`, and it is documented here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#collections

However, be warned that those docs currently say the following:

> Note: Keep in mind that the Kubernetes API does not have a kind named List.
>
> kind: List is a client-side, internal implementation detail for processing > collections that might be of different kinds of object. Avoid depending on > kind: List in automation or other code.

When using json (via jsonnet or similar), I don't see any reasonable lightweight alternative to `kind: List`.  It would be nice if there was an officially supported way to just do this:

```
jsonnet foo.jsonnet | kubectl apply -f -
```

There are tools like kubecfg and tanka that deal with it, but that's heavier weight, and unnecessarily.

It might be good to try to get the jsonnet maintainer (a googler) to talk to the kubectl maintainers (obviously also googlers) to make `kind: List` officially supported.  Also, my guess is that enough people already depend upon `kind: List` that the `kubectl` maintainers are forced to support it at this point.  It would just be nice if the documentation could align with the likely reality to reduce anxiety when using it.

Looking around for usage of `kind: List`...

- Here's an example of a globally important Helm chart using it https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/issues/890
- kube-libsonnet is also using it: https://github.com/kube-libsonnet/kube-libsonnet/blob/v1.22.2/kube.libsonnet#L141-L146
- Tanka doesn't use it, but is aware it's tempting people : )
  https://github.com/grafana/tanka/blob/main/docs/docs/jsonnet/main.md#list-type